# Can I uninstall one of two different versions of Powershell 5?

Tags: powershell

Somehow, I have two versions of Windows PowerShell 5 installed.

The x86 version is in

```
%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

the other version (64, my system is a 64 bit system) is in

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

The executables have the same timestamp, they are not the same, and neither are their directories.

I know I should leave PS version 5 alongside PS 7 (of which I also have 7.3 and a 7.4 preview). I'm trying to minimize confusion. Can I uninstall the PS 5 x86 version without breaking anything, and if so, how?

Comment: Having a 32-bit implementation of Windows PowerShell alongside a 64-bit implementation is by design (and the executables differ of necessity, given that they target different CPU architectures). These two implementations are in sync in terms of version number (and therefore behavior) and are kept in sync during updates. I suggest not worrying about it - removing it may break things.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks. I guess I'll relabel the shortcuts to make things clearer.